# How to count specific occurrences of strings within chr data into a new column

Tags: r, datatable, data.table

I have a `dt` similar to below, with `chr` data held in the Description column like below. I need to count the number of times certain strings of characters occur in that column, and sum them in the Occurrences column.

In the table below, it would be counting the number of times "A18" or "A19" appears.

| ID | Date | Description | Occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | A1901,A1804,A2008,AB06 | *2* |
| 2 | 2020-01-14 | A1402,A1805,A1902 | *2* |
| 3 | 2018-02-25 | A1702 | *0* |

I'm very new to R and datatables, so haven't tried much. I've searched, but only found how to count occurrences of whole strings, not within them.

Comment: It's important to know some details of the object in question. Could you `dput(head(dt, 3))` and paste the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_count`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Occurences2 = str_count(Description, "A18|A19"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much - the stringr worked perfectly. I adapted your suggestion for 'data.table' as follows, and it works great.

'dt2 <- dt[,Occurrences2:=str_count(Descriptiont,"A18|A19")]'